# Struts2 creating local variables

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am writing

```
<s:set name="varName" value="ActionVariableValue"/>
```

and Accessing it as

```
<% int xyz=Integer.parseInt(varName);%>
```

but is saying varName does not exist.
it is accessible through  but not through above tag.
Please specify a way to get the value os var name through jsp element.

Comment: Apart from the *question* being a non-question, 2017 is near and scriptlets are dead more than a decade ago. Avoid them, even for legacy. Just refactor, or rewrite